# Custom AuthenticationFilter with Shiro's JndiObjectFactory

Tags: java, shiro, java-ee-7

I'm integrating Apache Shiro 1.3.2 in a Java EE 7 web application. For configuration purposes I'd like to use managed beans (CDI and EJB).

The `org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory` works great for setting up custom realms:

```java
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "dynamicRealm", JndiObjectFactory.class.getName());
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "dynamicRealm.requiredType", jndiClass.getName());
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "dynamicRealm.resourceName", jndiLookupPath(jndiClass));
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "securityManager.realms", "$dynamicRealm"); // , $...
```

But it doesn't seem to work for `authc`:

```
Ini ini = new Ini();
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "authc", JndiObjectFactory.class.getName());
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "authc.requiredType", jndiClass.getName());
ini.setSectionProperty("main", "authc.resourceName", jndiLookupPath(jndiClass));
```

Shiro does not use my provided custom sub-class of `AuthenticationFilter` but always defaults to `FormAuthenticationFilter` that redirects me to `/login.jsp`.

Is JNDI lookup of `AuthenticationFilter` not supported or is there another approach?

Comment: Are you sure it is the authc filter that is doing the redirect and not a role/permissions filter?  What does your path to filter mapping look like?

Comment: Actually the only place that contains '/login.jsp' is `AccessControlFilter` and `FormAuthenticationFilter` uses the constant from there. Do I have to configure the `loginUrl` multiple times? For each filter?

Comment: if you define 'shiro.loginUrl' it will be set for any filter you define (well, any filter that has a `setLoginUrl()` method, that is)

Comment: @BrianDemers Thanks for your reply. I tried  'shiro.loginUrl' with no effect.

Comment: What do your protected paths look like? (annotations or ini), can you include an example that is failing?